# Cache Organisation

Tags: cache, computer-architecture

Whats's the difference between **Direct Mapping** and **Four-way Set Associative**? They both mean that certain blocks of the cache are ***associated*** with certain parts of the main memory.

The only difference I see is that the Four-way mapping limits it to only four cache blocks while Direct Mapping may be more or less than four. Am I right to say this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitive textbook treatment IMO is [Patterson-Hennessy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123747503). Online see wikipedia [CPU_cache#Associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Associativity).

Not right regarding Direct Mapping: "each entry in main memory can go in just one place in the cache".